# BackGammon Game

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I'm trying to write a server client application for a backgammon game using C# Windows Forms:
Server Side:
I have a picturebox with a backgammon board image, and I need to draw the checkers on it.
I wrote this so far.

```
private void drawboard()
   {
      int x = 82, y = 64;
      for (int s = 0; s < 6; s++)
      {
          darkstone[s] = new PictureBox();
          this.Controls.Add(darkstone[s]);
          darkstone[s].Location = new Point(x, y);
          darkstone[s].BackColor = Color.Black;
          x += 60;
          darkstone[s].Paint += new PaintEventHandler(stone_Paint);
      }
   }
    private void stone_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
   {
       SolidBrush blackbrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
       int x = 32, y = 20;
       for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
       {
           e.Graphics.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x, y, 25, 23);
           y += 22;
       }
       SolidBrush whitebrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
       int z = 32, w = 350;
       for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
       {    
           e.Graphics.FillEllipse(whitebrush, z, w, 25, 23);
           w -= 22;
       }
       blackbrush.Dispose();
       whitebrush.Dispose();
   }
```

And I called method drawboard() when my form loads, but no checkers are drawn.
Anyway, if I define a picturebox_paint event, and call method stone_paint(), the checkers are drawn on the board. but this solution is not ideal as I need each checker to be represented as a pictureBox as in method drawboard() for later purposes such as moving checkers across the board.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You haven't specified a size for the picture boxes. They will remain at the default size, which might not be what you want. Drawing a black checker on black background is not really visible. Do you have a picture box per stone or per board? It looks like a picture box per board but still you draw multiple checkers into a single picture box. Why is that?

Comment: You don't set the dimensions of picboxes. The back color of picboxes is black and you draw a black ellipse on them. It is not going to be visible. The w is 350, probably outside the picboxes borders.

Comment: even when I change the pictureBox color, i still have the same problem..

Comment: "The w is 350, probably outside the picboxes borders" 350 is still within the board size

Comment: The Scenario is that I have a picturebox on my form, with an image of the game board. I am trying to add small pictureboxex on the main picturebox (using this code) each representing a checker. If this can not be possible, what other solution might I try?

Comment: *350 is still within the board size*, you are drawing **on** the picBoxes you created and **not** on the main picBox. So it is too large. Also change   `this.Controls.Add(darkstone[s]);` (your main picBox covers the picBoxes you create cause you use the form as the parent) to `mainPicBox.Controls.Add(darkstone[s]);`.